# Discount calculation

Tags: cognito-forms

I've created a calculation field called "Total Number of Sessions"

```
=(NumberOfSessionsAge35+NumberOfSessionsGrade15+NumberOfSessionsGrade68+NumberOfSessionsGrade712)
```

I'd like to give a discount based on the number of sessions:

```
=(if TotalNumberOfSessions() > 3 then -TotalPrice*0.10 else if TotalNumberOfSessions() > 1 then -TotalPrice*.05 else 0)
```

But I get an error message saying:

> No applicable method 'TotalNumberOfSessions' exists in type 'Cognito.Forms.FormEntry.Edenacres1.SummerOutdoorsSignUpForm' at character 4

Can anyone help me set up the correct formula?

My form template is at this link:
https://www.cognitoforms.com/templates/shared/Edenacres1/SummerOutdoorsSignUpForm

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've already figured this out, but for completeness the () are what is causing Cognito Forms to think you are trying to call a method.

The formula will be something like:
=TotalNumberOfSessions > 3 ? -TotalPrice*0.10 : TotalNumberOfSessions > 1 ? -TotalPrice*.05 : 0